# Survival model with unusual time varying covariate

Tags: survival, time-varying-covariate

I want to find out whether the relative time when two particular procedures are performed affects the success of one of the procedures. My two variables are as follows:

1. When procedure A is performed relative to procedure B.  The value can vary from -24 months (in patients with A before B) to 0 months (simultaneous), to +24 months (in patients with A after B).
2. Time to failure after procedure B is performed.

However, I can't get the analysis to work via any statistics that I know of, the closest possibility that I am aware of is Cox proportional hazard regression model but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Do you care how long it's been since A was performed, or just if A has been performed? Eg, are you wondering if the effect of A 'wears off'?